# Call a javascript function from c# to replace a div

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

i have a web page in c#, in the codebehind i generate a url, on the aspx page i want to update an iframe to show this url.

after looking a while for the means to do this, i found i can register javascript to force the refresh of the iframe, but now i am experiencing a trouble.

no matter what i try, the url seems to never change, remaining at the on load defined url.

let me show you some of the code so you can see what i am doing and maybe help me with thi issue.

i have this string, who handles the url i want to go

```
public String currentMap = "google.com";
```

this is the function who registers the javascript

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        UtilityClass utility = new UtilityClass();
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.GetType(),
            "StartupScript",
            "Sys.Application.add_load(MyLoad);",
            true);}
```

this registers the javascript function, this function is suppoused to load a modified url, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function MyLoad(sender) {
       $get('maps').innerHTML += "<%= currentMap %>";
   }</script>
```

while i can see how i the inner html updates (you can see i use the =+ operator, because i wanted to see if i was adding something to the page), but the value for currentMap is always the same, and the iframe does not gets updated.

i launch a function, when i click an object in a gridview, this function does something like this.

```
currentMap = "<iframe src=\"somepages.html" id=\"viewerframe\"  width=\"100%\" height=\"450\"></iframe>"\"";
```

i can see the iframe updating, but the value remains at http://google.com (a test value hard coded).

how can i update the div so it shows the correct url in the iframe?

thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

To update the src of an iframe you can use this code:

```
//Set upload frame source
        var uploadUrl = '/Profile/upload.aspx?id=' + $.url().param('id').replace('/', '');
        $('#uploadFrame').prop('src', uploadUrl);
```

Comment: I have the exact code working for me locally. For fun, leave the iframe source blank on the initial load and see if it refreshes with javascript then.